# .net MVC search to query joined table

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a search function which looks up customer name, postcode, telephone number. I would also like the function to lookup a joined table CustomerContact to search against FirstName and Surname.

I have the following:

```
var customer = from c in db.Customer.Include(c => c.CustomerContact)
                select c;


if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    customer = customer.Where(c => c.CustomerName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                        || c.Postcode.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                        || c.CustomerContact.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                        || c.CustomerContact.Surname.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                        || c.Telephone.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()));
}
```

I am not getting any errors. It is just not returning any results when I search against FirstName and Surname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came across the answer to this while working on something else.

Here's my final code on this. Hope its useful to someone.

```
var customer = from c in db.Customer
               select c;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
{
    customer = customer.Where(c => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.CustomerID).Trim().Equals(searchString)
                        || c.CustomerName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())
                        || c.Postcode.ToUpper().Replace(" ", "").Equals(searchString.ToUpper().Replace(" ", ""))
                        || c.Telephone.ToUpper().Replace(" ", "").Equals(searchString.ToUpper().Replace(" ", ""))
                        || c.CustomerContact.Where(x => x.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())).Any()
                        || c.CustomerContact.Where(x => x.Surname.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper())).Any()
                        || c.CustomerContact.Where(x => (x.FirstName.ToUpper() + " " + x.Surname.ToUpper()).Contains(searchString.ToUpper())).Any());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

customer = customer.Include("CustomerContact").Where(...

Comment: Unfortunately not! I have updated my original question to show the full query.